# Problem with expiring kubernetes tokens in pulumi provider

Tags: kubernetes, pulumi

After I create a kubernetes cluster in pulumi, I get the following error when trying to delete it:

```
 error: configured Kubernetes cluster is unreachable: unable to load schema information from the API server: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
    If the cluster has been deleted, you can edit the pulumi state to remove this resource
```

I can refresh the credentials by running a targeted `pulumi refresh` and then a targeted `pulumi up` on the k8s provider. Is there an easier way to keep the kubernetes clusters updated without having to run the targeted commands all the time?